# Auction winner in one word

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a one-word term for a person who won the auction? *Top bidder* comes to my mind, but it's actually two words.

Comment: Why do you need one word? Two seem to suit you just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generally adopted term for this is ***successful bidder*** as recognized in commercial and, probably also, legal contexts.

Strictly speaking, the *highest bidder* is considered as the tentative 'winner'. If his bid is technically cleared and no objections are raised, he would be the 'successful bidder'. He may or may not eventually buy -- if he completes the formalities and pays up, he would be the 'buyer'.

A single word may be possible but can be a problem being different from the well-understood phrase.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty descriptive. Also thank you for fetching the commonly used terms.

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine Nice to be of help. You could see the logic in using the set phrase, though your need was for a single word! Can you fit in the phrase?

Answer (score 6):

Buyer? Only the top bidder can actually buy the auction lot.

Winner? There is only one winner (and you actually used the word *won* yourself).

Comment: I'm not with *buyer*, the successful bidder may or may not eventually buy. Not winner either -- that sounds inappropriate to me though not sure why.